# Await.result(observableDoc.toFuture, Duration.Inf) is giving null in spark cluster

Tags: mongodb, scala, spark-streaming

**Await.result(observableDoc.toFuture, Duration.Inf)** is giving null in spark cluster. It is working fine on my local machine

I am using scala driver API.
I have tried changing Duration time but not working in spark cluster.

```
val mongoClient = MongoClient("uriString")
val db = mongoClient.getDatabase("databasename")
val collection = db.getCollection("collectionName")
var observableDoc = collection.find(equal("my_id", "12345")).first

observableDoc.subscribe(new Observer[T] {
  println(funcname + " : Inside observableStatus subscribe start")
  logger.info(funcname + " : Inside observableStatus subscribe start")

  override def onNext(result: T): Unit = {
    println(funcname + " onNext")
    logger.info(funcname + " onNext")
  }

  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = {
    println(funcname + " Failed")
    logger.info(funcname + " Failed")
  }

  override def onComplete(): Unit = {
    println(funcname + " Complete")
    logger.info(funcname + " Complete")
  }

  println(funcname + " : Inside observableStatus subscribe end")
  logger.info(funcname + " : Inside observableStatus subscribe end")
})

val awaitedR = Await.result(observableDoc.toFuture, Duration.Inf)
```

Above code works fine on my local machine and getting the expected result but in spark cluster **awaitedR**  is showing null.

Comment: Stacktrace?

Often `awaitedR` will be packaged into `Try` so that it results in `Success` or `Failure`

Comment: Something like:

```
Try(waitedResult) match {
      case Success(f) => f.value.get 
      case Failure(_) =>
      // This should handle timeouts. What other ways can Future fail?
}
```